# What's the difference between CC2564 and CC2564MODN bluetooth TI chips?

Tags: microcontroller, bluetooth, flash

As per title,
what's the actual difference between these two chips?
I dug extensively the TI site but I cannot find such info..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CC2564 is Bluetooth 4.0 compliant. The CC2564MODN is Bluetooth 4.1 compliant.

> - ... Fully Compliant with the
>   Bluetooth 4.0 Specification Up to the HCI Layer

versus:

> - Fully Certified Bluetooth 4.1 Module
>
>   - Compliant Up to the HCI Layer

Comment: Ok, so you are telling me that you can get bluetooth 4.1 on top of a CC2564B chip? As I can see from the specs, it seems that the CC2564MODN uses a CC2564B chip at its core, plus a filter and a 38MHz XTAL.

Comment: I'm approximately 99% sure it's just a firmware difference.

Answer (score 1):

The CC2564 is a 76-pin IC in a 8mm square x 0.9mm high QFN package.
The CC2564MODN is a 33-pin module in a 7mm square x 1.4mm high package.

The MODN seems to cost about twice as much, but the package is far more friendly to work with. It probably includes a few extra odds & ends underneath the lid (voltage regs, RF filters maybe ...) which make it quicker & easier to integrate into a design.